# How to observe mutableStateOf in activity onCreate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

It seems the mutableStateOf is the better choice than liveData to work with compose, but in activity's onCreate method I can not observe it for my case, is it have a workaround or stick to use liveData in activity?

```
// viewModel
    var showError by mutableStateOf("")
        private set
// ...

// activity
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.showError.observe(this) {  // <- not work in activity
            if (it != "") {
                Toast.makeText(this, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                viewModel.onShowError()
            }
        }
    }
// ...
```

Comment: If `showError` is getting consumed by a composable, then using `mutableStateOf` is okay. But in your case, where it is being consumed by a non-composable UI, then `LiveData` is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `showError` as a `LiveData` in your ViewModel:

```
val _showError = mutableLiveData("")
val showError: LiveData
    get() = _showError
```

And then consume it from any composable code with the handy extension `observeAsState`:

```
val showErrorState = viewModel.showError.observeAsState()
```

So in your Activity you can use the `showError` directly exposed as a liveData

Comment: Tip: If you have a lot of properties like this in your ViewModel you can avoid duplicating a lot of backport fields and use the handy `liveData` coroutine builder which let you expose an immutable `liveData` object to consumers